# Spring Intergration MQTT, send response to gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, mqtt, spring-integration-http

Service:

```java
Message<MQTTResponse> response = mqttGateway.sendToMqtt("topic", jsonData);
    log.info("Receive reply{}",String.valueOf(response.getPayload()));
```

I have this `MessagingGateway`:

```java
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "mqttOutputChannel", defaultReplyChannel = "mqttResponseChannel")
public interface MqttGateway {
    Message<MQTTResponse> sendToMqtt(@Header(MqttHeaders.TOPIC) String topic, String data);
}
```

The constrain: `sendToMqtt` will send a request to a topic, the response of that topic will come from another topic. Which I will capture with `mqttInputChannel`

```java
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
public void handleMessage(Message<String> message) throws JsonProcessingException {
    if (Objects.equals(message.getHeaders().get("mqtt_receivedTopic"), topicAck)) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MQTTResponse payloadMap = objectMapper.readValue(message.getPayload(), MQTTResponse.class);
        log.info("Payload: {}", payloadMap);

        MessageChannel mqttResponseChannel = mqttResponseChannel();
        Message<MQTTResponse> responseMessage = MessageBuilder.
           withPayload(payloadMap)
           .setReplyChannel(mqttResponseChannel)
           .build();
        log.info("Response Message: {}", responseMessage);
        mqttResponseChannel.send(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

After the line `log.info("Response Message: {}", responseMessage);`, it lost connection immediately: `Lost connection: MqttException`.

And after a while: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.messaging.Message.getPayload()" because "response" is null`

I can't send the response received from `handleMessage` function back to the service with the reply channel `mqttResponseChannel`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not going to work that simple way. The `@MessagingGateway` is a request-reply pattern which does correlation between request and reply via `replyChannel` header with the `TemporaryReplyChannel` value.

When you receive message from another process, in your case the MQTT Inbound Channel Adapter, there is definitely not that info in the headers. And you cannot just send message to the `mqttResponseChannel` expecting it to be correlated with the request. Just because this message does not have that `replyChannel` header.

Usually for this kind of asynchronous correlation when request-reply is still blocking I suggest a solution with an aggregator. Which is really not so simple:

You send your request to the MQTT and to an aggregator with some unique correlation key which would be present some way in the request to MQTT.

When you receive a message from reply topic, you send to that aggregator as well. This reply message must have same correlation key info as a request. The aggregator then performs a correlation between request and reply. In the release function you extract headers from request message (usually the first in a group). And just return a reply message with those headers added. That would include the mentioned `replyChannel` for correlation with originator gateway. Your aggregator must not have an `outputChannel` and the framework will choose `replyChannel` header for the message to produce.

The crucial part of this pattern is to preserve the correlation key in the MQTT request and reply.

See more info about an aggregator in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/aggregator.html